# Lombok for Domain Object in Hexagonal Architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I just learned about hexagonal architecture and want to implement it in my project using java programming language. From what I learned, in this architecture, layers containing object/entity domains must be made independent (not dependent on other dependencies). The question is can I use the lombok dependency on layers containing object/entity domains to reduce boilerplate code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lombok to avoid boilerplate code. It doesn't affect any architectural pattern. If you want to achieve special cases then you can override getter/setter/constructor/hashcode/equals/toString/build.

Check out more at https://projectlombok.org/features/. Lombok is a compile-time dependency only.